# Symfony2 Embedded forms, How to persist objects

Tags: symfony

I am trying to implement [Embedded Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) (Symfony2, 2.7), with Task and Tag entities, One2Many.

To save reference to the Task object into a Tag record,  I am able to define Task's createAction() only by:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Task entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="MyName_Task_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("MyNameBundleBlogBundle:Task:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($task);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $tags = $task->getTags();
        foreach($tags as $tg){$tg->setTask($task); $em->persist($tg);}   // <-- do I really need to loop?
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MyName_Task_show', array('id' => $task->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $task,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

EDIT: I know it should work without the loop straightforwardly, but it does not. Question is: What should I look for which I might have written wrong? See [related question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119007/symfony2-2-7-embedded-forms-persist-failure?noredirect=1#comment221663_119007)

Note, I have:

```
class Task{
....
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="Task", cascade={"persist"} )
 */
private $Tags;
....
 /**
 * Add tag
 *
 * @param \MyName\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
 *
 * @return Task
 */
public function addTag(\MyName\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tag;
    $tag->setTask($this);
    return $this;
}
}
```

Comment: Persisting the task is all you need to do.  The cascade=persist will take care of persisting the tags.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I have a three layers Job/Task/Tag  situation. Does it make a difference? I'll try to fix, or make another question.

Comment: As long as you have your cascade=persist set correctly on your relations then one persist is all you need.

Comment: @Cerad, all, if you spot something wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225089/symfony2-2-7-embedded-forms-how-to-persist-objects, I appreciate

Comment: Before starting a new question you really should finish this one.  You have two correct answers.  Really should accept one or state why not.

Comment: I could accept either, but I don't get a clue about what could have gone wrong. (Since it works by a brute force loop, it does not seem to be a silly typo).

Comment: Other question moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119007/symfony2-2-7-embedded-forms-persist-failure

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to loop through all `tags` and explicitly set `task`, Symfony will do that for you if you configure it correctly.

The only thing you need to add is set `by_reference` to `false` inside your form builder. In this case, symfony will explicitly will call `setTask` on every `tag`.

For more info ['by_reference'](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference)

Comment: No need for by_reference here.  His setTag implementation takes care of the cross referencing.

Comment: He can remove that line too.

Comment: Not sure which line you are talking about but the $tag->setTask($this) line should stay and makes keeping the object references in sync much easier.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Cerad comment, the only thing you have to do is persist the `Task`.

All related tags will be automatically persisted, thanks to `cascade={"persist"}` in your association mapping.

Your code should be :

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($task);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MyName_Task_show', array('id' => $task->getId())));
}
```

See the [Etablishing associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#establishing-associations) and [Cascade operations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) chapters of Doctrine documentation.